# Dell inspiron 1370 screen split into 6

Tags: motherboard, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 1370, it has nvidia G105M . The fault is, when I run the laptop its screen split into 6 portions. Before that began to happen, Windows had showed a "driver not responding" warning and after that it just runs in 6 screen portions.

Comment: Are you able to boot into safe mode?

Comment: Yes, I boot it into safe mode, sometimes it goes fine in safe mode.

Comment: A photo of the issue would be helpful in understanding your problem.

Comment: My problem visual look likes the same as in this pic of following link: http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwstaw.org%2Fimages%2Ffree%2F2009%2F09%2F25%2F5e51a52a5098bfcd915c8b96075ccd.jpeg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.gentoo.org%2Fviewtopic-t-794174-start-0.html&h=1536&w=2048&tbnid=-2Az4ivMSaWr6M%3A&zoom=1&docid=FiBaSfI8M6aM8M&ei=xj5qVKKVF4XeaqnvgbAE&tbm=isch&ved=0CCAQMygFMAU&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1277&page=1&start=0&ndsp=19

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to install the latest driver from Dell? You can  visit the Dell Drivers and Downloads page for your device and check for new drivers

Also check for hardware issues

Run the Dell diagnostics before OS load. Pressing F12 several when the Dell logo appears will start the diagnostic.

There is also the Dell PC Checkup. This is a diagnostic tool that is part of the Dell Support Center application that comes preinstalled on your computer. To open the Dell Support Center application, click Start, point to All Programs, click Dell Support Center, and then click PC Checkup.  It can be downloaded if missing from your system

You can also do an online health check

1. Go to the Dell Consumer Services page.
2. Click Begin Checkup to download the PC Health Check application.
3. Run the installation wizard.
4. Review the End-User License Agreement, and click I agree.
5. Start My Scan to begin your system scan.

Comment: I installed the latest driver by updating it on windows 7 device manager, but there are no positive results shown up.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is best to install from the Dell site or by using the Dell update tools.